# two spaces as scanf delimeter

Tags: c

I was hoping to be able to scan a string with this format

```
"hello world        !!!!"
```

to

```
{"hello world", "!!!!"}
```

This 2 strings are separated with more than 1 space. Can I parse this or at least detect 2 consecutive spaces in scanf?

Comment: These are three strings, not two. To read multiple characters regardless of whitespace, you can use fgets() and then parse the whole string.

Comment: To detect two consecutive spaces you can use the [`strstr()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr) function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code could help you

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char a_buf[5][100] = {0}, sep[3] ,*buf = a_buf[0];
    int i = 0;
    buf = a_buf[0];
    while (scanf("%s%2[ ]",buf,sep) > 1) {
        if (strlen(sep)==1)
        {
            buf += strlen(buf);
            *buf++ = ' ';
        }
        else
            buf = a_buf[++i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From your question, it seems like you are not interested in the fact that there are more than one spaces, but just for a way to parse them.

Fear not! A single space character in `*scanf` already ignores *all* whitespace (including `'\n'`, `'\r'`, `'\t'` and `'\v'` in "C" locale). So in the simplest form, you could read like this:

```
scanf("%s %s", str1, str2);
```

Of course, you would need error checking. One safe way would be:

```
char str1[100];
char str2[100];

scanf("%99s", str1);
ungetc('x', stdin);
scanf("%*s");

scanf("%99s", str2);
ungetc('x', stdin);
scanf("%*s");
```

Which is a generally safe way (not related to your particular question).

The `ungetc` + `scanf("%*s")` ignore what is left of the string (if any). Note that you wouldn't need any space before the second `scanf("%99s")` because `scanf` already ignores all whitespace before `%s` (and in fact before all `%*` except `%c` and `%[`).

---

If you really want to make sure there are at least two spaces, and you insist on using `scanf`, you could do like this:

```
    char str1[100];
    char str2[100];
    char c;

    scanf("%99s", str1);
    ungetc('x', stdin);
    scanf("%*s");

    scanf("%c", &c);
    if (c != ' ')
        goto exit_not_two_spaces;
    scanf("%c", &c);
    if (c != ' ')
        goto exit_not_two_spaces;

    scanf("%99s", str2);
    ungetc('x', stdin);
    scanf("%*s");

    return /* success */
exit_not_two_spaces:
    ungetc(c, stdin);
    return /* fail */
```

Answer (score -1):

According to the c++ reference ( http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/ )

> the function will read and ignore any whitespace characters encountered before the next non-whitespace character (whitespace characters include spaces, newline and tab characters -- see isspace). A single whitespace in the format string validates any quantity of whitespace characters extracted from the stream (including none).

I think you should use gets: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/gets/ and then parse the string returned.

EDIT. Use fgets(), not gets()

Comment: You should *never*, ever, no matter the circumstances, use gets(). Use fgets() instead.

Comment: `gets` is extremely unsafe as there is no way to prevent buffer overflows. At least suggest `fgets`. Not to mention that C11 removed `gets` altogether.